# Scraping Twitter data with R results in Arabic text being garbled

Tags: r, twitter, arabic

I'm using RStudio (3.3.1) on macOS Sierra (10.12.5) to scrape the user profile information of the followers of certain Twitter users.

My problem is that when a user's profile description is in Arabic the text that is returned is garbled. For example,this user description:

> جزائريٌّ يسري دمُ الشهداء في عروقِه ويطلُب العِلم حتّى يعلم الذين
>   كفروا أنّ دين الإسلام هو دينُ الحق ،والحقَّ أقُول..

becomes this:

> Ø¬Ø²Ø§Ø¦Ø±ÙŠÙ‘ÙŒ ÙŠØ³Ø±ÙŠ Ø¯Ù…Ù Ø§Ù„Ø´Ù‡Ø¯Ø§Ø¡ ÙÙŠ Ø¹Ø±ÙˆÙ‚ÙÙ‡
>   ÙˆÙŠØ·Ù„ÙØ¨ Ø§Ù„Ø¹ÙÙ„Ù…  Ø­ØªÙ‘Ù‰ ÙŠØ¹Ù„Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø°ÙŠÙ† ÙƒÙØ±ÙˆØ§ Ø£Ù†Ù‘
>   Ø¯ÙŠÙ† Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…  Ù‡Ùˆ Ø¯ÙŠÙ†Ù Ø§Ù„Ø­Ù‚ ØŒÙˆØ§Ù„Ø­Ù‚Ù‘ÙŽ
>   Ø£Ù‚ÙÙˆÙ„.. #Ø£Ù†Ø´Ø· Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ ØµÙØ­Ø©

This is particularly problematic as the project I am working on is focused on Muslim users of Twitter and a lot of the data is in Arabic.

I'm guessing this is a problem with the encoding and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347285/2560171) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068076/arabic-text-not-showing-in-r) suggested updating to RStudio 3.3.3 but when I tried that it made no difference and I had issues with the compatibility of some of my packages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this Twitter word cloud with Arabic text, though I can't read Arabic, so who knows how successful it was.[Word cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AwAq.png) That's based in part on:

```
# Get some tweets
trump_tweets <- userTimeline("RTarabic", n = 1000)

# Extract the text
trump_text <- iconv(trump_text, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')
trump_text <- sapply(trump_tweets, function(x) x$getText())
```

I think making it into UTF-8 is the key, but I admit I barely know what I'm talking about here.